# Locate exactly at Google play store, some app's screenshots field and "rate this app" field

Tags: android, google-play, screenshot, rate

I know how to locate at some app in Google Play, by Android program with hyper link, like:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+ getPackageName().toString().trim()));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Is there a way to locate exactly at the field of its "screenshots" and "rate this app" field?
i.e. the hyper link to directly jump to the below two field location inside the pages of Google Play.
What I want is to direct to these two fields,by program, to guide users more exactly without confusion.

[image: After you you tap on the screenshots]   [image: the rate and review field]

For example , this is the main page of the app with its screenshots. The rate field and certain one specific screenshot are just some sub-field or sub-link in the main page of the app.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
[image: the app's main page]

Answer (score 0):

-after analyzing the webpage source of Google play, find that it can be located at the "rate this app" field by https://play.google.com/store/ereview?docId= [package name]. Such as for the Google app:

https://play.google.com/store/ereview?docId=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

But when linking from Android program, it appears error message " To view this content, install and set up a web browsing app."

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/ereview?docId="+ getPackageName().toString().trim()));
        startActivity(intent);
```

-To locate at the individual screenshot on the app in Google Play, like below link

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/QeWRpD6LfSl8p98A_4f-QI6M2ayyyJ3FvNplG6Sww_iczHFHOJZimuEcaj0z9hwh5g=h900-rw

But it doesn't have the arrows to browse one-by-one. Another problem is that if the developer changes the screenshots, the hyper-link may change also.